# Rails search with multiple queries not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I know my code is clunky, but I am trying to have a form with multiple text boxes for different columns in my `GUEST` database.  The form is not working and all my guest entries are still listed (the list is not narrowed down by the search). If anyone could possibly point me in the correct direction that would be awesome.  Also how could the guest.rb code be more concise?

Controller:

```
def index
    @guests = Guest.all
    if params[:search_first_name]
      @guests = Guest.search_first_name(params[:search_first_name])
    end
    if params[:search_last_name]
      @guests = Guest.search_last_name(params[:search_last_name])
    end
    if params[:search_email]
      @guests = Guest.search_email(params[:search_email])
    end
    if params[:search_phone]
      @guests = Guest.search_phone(params[:search_phone])
    end
  end
```

guest.rb

```
def self.search_first_name(query)
        # where(:email, query) -> This would return an exact match of the query
        where("first_name like ?", "%#{query}%") 
      end

      def self.search_last_name(query)
        # where(:email, query) -> This would return an exact match of the query
        where("last_name like ?", "%#{query}%") 
      end

      def self.search_email(query)
        # where(:email, query) -> This would return an exact match of the query
        where("email like ?", "%#{query}%") 
      end

      def self.search_phone(query)
        # where(:email, query) -> This would return an exact match of the query
        where("phone like ?", "%#{query}%") 
      end
```

index.html:

```
<%= form_tag(guests_path, :method => "get", class: "navbar-form", id: "search-form") do %>
          <div class="input-append col-sm-10">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <p><%= text_field_tag :search_first_name, params[:search_first_name], placeholder: "First Name", style: "width:100%;" %></p>
              <p><%= text_field_tag :search_last_name, params[:search_last_name], placeholder: "Last Name", style: "width:100%;" %></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <p><%= text_field_tag :search_email, params[:search_email], placeholder: "Email Address", style: "width:100%;" %></p>
              <p><%= text_field_tag :search_phone, params[:search_phone], placeholder: "Phone Number", style: "width:100%;" %></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">

            </div>
              <%= submit_tag 'Search Guests' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>

<table class="table table-hover col-sm-12">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Guest ID</th>
      <th>Guest Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @guests.each do |guest| %>
      <tr>
        <td>G-00<%= guest.id %></td>
        <td><%= guest.first_name %> <%= guest.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= guest.email %></td>
        <td><%= guest.phone %></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;"><%= link_to 'View Guest Profile', guest, :class => "btn btn-sm btn-success" %> <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_guest_path(guest), :class => "btn btn-sm btn-default" %> <%= link_to 'Destroy', guest, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => "btn btn-sm btn-danger" %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: When your page is displayed after searching, are any of the search fields filled in with what you submitted?

Comment: Yes the fields are still filled in after searching and the URL reflects that as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes because a param without a value will be equal to `""` which is still `true` in Ruby, so basically if your `search_phone` is ever empty then you'll see all the results because `if params[:search_phone]` will be true and so that block will be run, and the eventual code that's run will be equivalent to:

```
@guests = Guest.where( "phone like '%%'" )
```

Which is just two wildcards, and will therefore return all results.  Other people have already mentioned changing that conditional to use `.present?` so it won't be run if it's blank.

You also asked about refactoring the code, I would write it like so:

#### controller

```
def index
  @guests = Guest.search_or_all params
end
```

#### model

```
def self.search_or_all params={}
  query = %i[first_name last_name email phone].map do |k|
    kk = "search_#{k}"
    sanitize_sql ["#{k} LIKE '%s'", "%#{params[kk]}%"] if params[kk]
  end.compact.join " OR "
  where query
end
```

Comment: Sorry, made a small correction, I had `=` instead of `LIKE`

Comment: Should this also strip the word ```search_```? Ideally you wouldn't have that in the first place.

Comment: Nice refactoring. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

Without going deep into a code refactoring. Try adding `params[:field_name].present?` to all the `if` statements.

Answer (score -1):

You should put `"^#{query}"` to make this work as a regular expression.
This way your Guest.rb file will look like this

Guest.rb

```
  def self.search_first_name(query)
    # where(:email, query) -> This would return an exact match of the query
    where("first_name like ?", "^#{query}") 
  end

  def self.search_last_name(query)
    # where(:email, query) -> This would return an exact match of the query
    where("last_name like ?", "^#{query}") 
  end

  def self.search_email(query)
    # where(:email, query) -> This would return an exact match of the query
    where("email like ?", "") 
  end

  def self.search_phone(query)
    # where(:email, query) -> This would return an exact match of the query
    where("phone like ?", "%#{query}%") 
  end
```